# Using interface or Super class as data type for instantiating sub class

Tags: java

I am new to Java, sorry if this is a dumb question but it really bothers me. I can't find real answer anywhere on Internet, probably because I don't know how to ask it in short term.

I have seen tutorials where teacher uses Interface or Parent class name as data type to reference obj.

- Why is that possible?
- More importantly why does he do it?
- When should I do it?

If my questions are confusing, this code will explain my questions better:

```
Runnable obj = new Thread();
/*instead of*/
Thread obj = new Thread();
```

This goes for Parent classes as well:

```
public class A{}
public class B extends A{}
A obj = new B();
```

I am aware that objects are created in heap by the "new Class()" syntax and that variable doesn't actually contain object but rather location of an object.There are also rules for that reference variable "data type".
I can't go around and do stuff like:

```
C obj = new B();
```

So rules state that "data type" must be part (interface, parent) of the class being instantiated.
Why is that an option?
Why do people do it?
Should I do it as well?
What is god?
Is there good reason (bigger picture) for all of that or is it just random (more options) feature provided by Java?

**Edit:**

***I'm new to Stackoverflow so I unknowingly marked this post as duplicate to one, which it isn't duplicate of.***

I'm updating this in case someone like me bumps into the same question and dont knowe how to google it out, because of unfamiliar/unknown concept name/term.
Now that everything is clear, let's jump to the enlightenment.

When we use Interface or Parent class as data type of the reference variable
we'r telling Java to create an object that will be trimmed down (as i understand it) and contain only the properties and methods that exist in Interface or Parent class that we used as a Data Type.

I'll take ArrayList class as example code:

```
//dont pay attention to the generics,im using it for a good practice
Collection<Integer> obj = new ArrayList<>(); 

/*This works! Because add method is defined in Collection Interface
aswell as ArrayList class duhhh...*/
obj.add(3); 

/*This gives compilation time error.Because method doesnt exist in
Collection interface but it is valid method in ArrayList class*/
obj.indexOf(3);
```

Same goes for the Parent Class DataType heres an example:

```
public class foo {
   public void sayHarro() {
      System.out.println("Harro from foo");
   }

   public void stateYourGendre() {
      System.out.println("I indentify myself as fooSexual");
   }
}

public class bar extends foo {
   public void sayHarro() {
      System.out.println("Harro from bar");
   }

   public void madeInBar() {
      System.out.println("im genuine");
   }
}

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         foo obj = new bar();

         /*No Problem!Everything is legit.Method exists in foo!
         Outputs: Harro from bar*/
         obj.sayHarro();

         /*
         *No Problem! Method exists in foo and is inherited, though not 
         *overwritten (redeclared in bar). 
         *Outouts: I indentify myself as fooSexual
         */
         obj.stateYourGendre();

         /* 
         *Now we have a Compile time error, because method doesnt exist
         *in provided DataType of the reference variable though it's 
         *valid bar class method.
         */
         obj.madeInBar();
    }
}
```

Everything is clear now to me atleast, I hope to you aswell. Allthough now the question arise to which i do not have an answear.

- Is the new created object actualy (trimmed down) stripped of methods and properties that cannot be found in provided DataType?
- If so does that object actualy take less memory space than it would if it was whole?

Also note above that i said it'll be trimmed down but i added extra note ***"as i understand it"*** **! It's important to note that until new questions have been answeared by someone with actual knowledge.** Because if it's not trimmed than all this stuff is just for making more strict and depricating code.
Also i'd really like to knowe the name for this whole concept if there is one.
May the heap be with you!

Comment: You'd do well to research a concept called "polymorphism".  Also of note are "covariance and contravariance".  Sometimes it's useful for a variable, method parameter, method return type, etc. to be of a less specific type than the object it references.  This helps code be more generic.  As a contrived example, consider a method which takes two numeric parameters and returns their sum.  You could write a separate method for integers, doubles, longs, etc.  *Or* you could write a single method which accepts any generic "addable" type and returns their sum, regardless of what they are.

Comment: I think i understand it.What bothered me is that he used it in such example,that it couldnt explain itself.There was no generic reason to do so. I guess thats all to it then? Thanks for clearing my mind.Kind regards.